# database in objective is not copying after edit in db file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite

I have a database file with .db extension and want to copy to device it was working fine on OS9 but i edit .db file and replace it with previous file but it is creating file of 0byte. i have clean build but problem doestnot solved.

Comment: why .db extension use instead of .sqlite ?

Comment: bcz of requirements .

Comment: yes but what is the use of this . e.g data store ?

Comment: yes it need to be store. error coming in cpying file from foler to device storage.. if i replaced forceforully db works fine